# Is there a way to store similar functions in a dictionary with a loop?

Tags: python, function, loops, dictionary

Suppose you have a family of similar functions:

```py
def cos_fit1(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

def cos_fit2(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

# and so on..

def cos_fit8(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

I want to put them into a dictionary. Currently it's done this way:

```py
func_dict = {
1 : cos_fit1,
2 : cos_fit2
# and so on..
}
```

I am wondering, is there an more elegant way of doing this? Obviously this scales up really badly.
I've tried this, but it's only the function's name as a string which is in the dictionary.

```py
func_dict = {i : f'cos_fit{i}' for i in range(1, 8)}
```

Edit:

```py
func_dict = {i : eval(f'cos_fit{i}') for i in range(1, 8)}
```

works, but is it a good practice?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're searching this:

```
index_position = len("cos_fit")
func_dict = {int(name[index_position:]): globals()[name]
             for name in globals()
             if name.startswith("cos_fit")}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, but why do this?

```
func_dict = {f'cos_fit{i}': lambda *args, **kwargs: "" for i in range(8)}
```